# Внутренние классы в интерфейсах

Tags: java, классы

Буквально сегодня столкнулся со спецификацией интерфейса в котором реализован внутренний класс. Можете обьяснить - зачем вообще делать внутренние классы в интерфейсах? Какую цель преследуют разработчики используя такую структуру?

```
public interface IInterface {
    void init();

    private class ClassInInterface{
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Видимо, назначение класса тесно связано с этим интерфейсом, при этом сам класс маленький (dto-шка, хэлпер или фабрика) и вытаскивать в отдельный файл не хотелось.